# QGIS is asking for credentials every time I open a project saved in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I recently migrated my PostGIS database to a new system. I have some QGIS projects saved in there but now every time I try to open a project a dialog pops up asking me for credentials. It also says "Definition of service XXX not found". If I ignore the dialog, none of my layers are found, yet I have access to them if I load them from the database.

I think this has to do with me setting up an authentication system in my previous QGIS setup.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi ! QGis is looking for the authentication config with the name written after 'authcfg=', so you shoukd create one with that name (next to the yellow lock) with your credentials inside. HTH

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I still get the same error. I remember creating a service file to avoid entering credentials on every session. The service file was probably named local_gisdb. However, I can't remember how I did this. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: This behaviour of QGIS is not totally clear to me, but I'd say that if you want to avoid entering the credentials each time, you should define a connection to a Postgis database - without any reference to this service file - and specify an authentication config which is where you will store your credentials.